# Regular expression that returns first number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Iam trying to create regular expression, that select all except first found number. For example in this string: `abc,abc-145,dsa,26,dsa`
I need to create regular expression, that will return all except number `145`. In other words I need regular, that I can use in `preg_replace` with php and I will get only number 145

Comment: `\d+`. Please bring some effort in solving **your tasks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to return the first match result.

```
$str = 'abc,abc-145,dsa,26,dsa';
preg_match('~\d+~', $str, $match);
echo $match[0]; //=> "145"
```

The token `\d` matches a digit. `+` quantifies this token "one or more" times.

If your desire is to use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to get the same result:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\D*(\d+).*~', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: @zerkms - But is that what the OP really needs?

Comment: @zerkms Agreed. But OP also said "get" the number 145.

Comment: @hwnd I need glasses!! /cc STLDeveloper